# Can a process have two receive blocks

Tags: process, erlang

My working environment is Erlang.
Can a process having 2 different functions have two receive blocks in the different functions.

```
receive
....
end.

request()
PID!(message)
%% Can i get the reply back here instead of the receive block above?
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, you can have many `receive` expressions. When one is evaluated it will take the first matching message out of the message queue/mailbox (take your pick of names) and leave the rest for the next `receive`. Sending a message, using the `Pid ! Message` syntax (the only way), is completely asynchronous and just adds the message to the end of the receiving processes message queue. `receive` is the only way to *receive* messages i.e. take them out of the message queue. You can never put them back.

There is no built-in synchronous message passing in Erlang, it is one by sending two messages:

- The "requesting" process sends a message to the receiving process and then goes into a `receive` to wait for the reply.
- The "receiving" process will itself get the message in a `receive`, process it, send the reply message back the the "requesting" process and then go into a `receive` to sit and wait for the next message.

Remember there is no inherent connection between processes, ever, and all communication is done using asynchronous message sending and `receive`.

So in reply to your second question: you can **ONLY** get a reply back in a `receive` expression. That is the only way!

Sorry to be a bit pedantic but Erlang doesn't have either blocks or statements. It is a functional language and only has *expressions* which always return a value even if the return value is sometimes ignored.

Answer (score 2):

Of couse, you can.

> Receives messages sent to the process using the send operator (!). The
>   patterns Pattern are sequentially matched against the first message in
>   time order in the mailbox, then the second, and so on. If a match
>   succeeds and the optional guard sequence GuardSeq is true, the
>   corresponding Body is evaluated. The matching message is consumed,
>   that is removed from the mailbox, while any other messages in the
>   mailbox remain unchanged.

The following code is from `supervisor2.erl` of `rabbitmq` project. It even uses nested `receive` statement. I have marked nested `receive` below.

```
terminate_simple_children(Child, Dynamics, SupName) ->
    Pids = dict:fold(fun (Pid, _Args, Pids) ->
                         erlang:monitor(process, Pid),
                         unlink(Pid),
                         exit(Pid, child_exit_reason(Child)),
                         [Pid | Pids]
                     end, [], Dynamics),
    TimeoutMsg = {timeout, make_ref()},
    TRef = timeout_start(Child, TimeoutMsg),
    {Replies, Timedout} =
        lists:foldl(
          fun (_Pid, {Replies, Timedout}) ->
                  {Reply, Timedout1} =
                      receive %% attention here 
                          TimeoutMsg ->
                              Remaining = Pids -- [P || {P, _} <- Replies],
                              [exit(P, kill) || P <- Remaining],
                              receive {'DOWN', _MRef, process, Pid, Reason} -> %%attention here
                                      {{error, Reason}, true}
                              end;
                          {'DOWN', _MRef, process, Pid, Reason} ->
                              {child_res(Child, Reason, Timedout), Timedout};
                          {'EXIT', Pid, Reason} -> 
                              receive {'DOWN', _MRef, process, Pid, _} ->
                                      {{error, Reason}, Timedout}
                              end
                      end,
                  {[{Pid, Reply} | Replies], Timedout1}
          end, {[], false}, Pids),
    timeout_stop(Child, TRef, TimeoutMsg, Timedout),
    ReportError = shutdown_error_reporter(SupName),
    [case Reply of
         {_Pid, ok}         -> ok;
         {Pid,  {error, R}} -> ReportError(R, Child#child{pid = Pid})
     end || Reply <- Replies],
    ok.
```